# How can a voltage multiplier be used as variable resistance?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ota

I am interested in voltage control and variable resistance and I have tried with OTA, vactrol, and diode. I read that a voltage multiplier (DC to DC?) can be used for this purpose. Is this multiplier a four quadrant multiplier? Can someone explain how it is used as a variable resistor, preferably floating?

Comment: Single quadrant resistor i.e. positive voltage and positive current? Or something more demanding?

Comment: I would appreciate any info.

Comment: **Disambiguating your title**  as “Voltage a multiplier” usually refers to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier . On the other hand, I believe that you wish an “Analog Multiplier” as briefly mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_multiplier. Please review what your really wish and consider revising your question.

Comment: Thanks I have confused the terms...

Comment: I think some DC to DC converters are able to be used as analog multipliers if i am not mistaken. @EJE

Comment: The text of the question clearly asks for guidance here so, making the assumption that it means one or the other, contradicts the body of the question i.e. *Is this multiplier a four quadrant multiplier?*. So I've rolled it back to how it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would appreciate any info*

You can make a fairly-accurate single-quadrant resistor by designing a current sink like this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/lt1001-precision-current-sink-why-the-jfet/). Note that the JFET can be left out with a slight loss of accuracy. So, you have a current sink whose current value is dictated by Vin.

So, if you then allow Vin to be connected to the Iout terminal, the current is proportional to the voltage applied and, of course, that's resistance.

**Simulation of a 1 kΩ resistor**

[image]

V2 is varied from 0 volts to 10 volts and, the current through R4 (a fixture in my simulator) varies from 0 mA to 10 mA. Altering the potential divider ratio (R1 and R2) adjusts the variable resistor. So, at the moment, the circuit mimics a 1 kΩ resistor.

And, the potential divider formed by R1 and R2 can be supplemented with a single quadrant voltage multiplier. Hence, you can make a variable resistor that is modulated by an input voltage signal: -

[image]

Comment: You can't connect the opamp V+ to VIN because that leaves no headroom for the transistor. So connect to VIN with a R divider which adjusts to  change the emulated R. Small errors from BJR beta etc. can break mitigated by using a MOSFET.

Comment: Although I found your circuit interesting, it does not seem to me to be an analog multiplier, as seems to be asked by the OP. But I might be mistaken, as I’m not as knowledgeable in Electronics as you and other EE here.

Comment: @jp314 I'm not sure what you are driving at?

Comment: @EJE I was working on that bit I.e. how to use a multiplier to make a variable resistor.

Comment: the answer included "Vin to be connected to the Iout terminal" -- that's where you run out of headroom. Later edits show R dividers ==> OK.

Comment: Ok, I just saw this supplement. But how the *multiplier* block (between R1-R2 x V3) is electronically made? I believe *that* is the main point.

Comment: I suppose the multiplier can be a vca. One last question. R4 is a 0Ω resistor? Can I use a piece of wire in place of it? Will it act as floating points to take the place of a real resistor? And can the circuit work with bipolar signals? Very good explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnAm R4 is just a 0 ohm resistor that I can use in my simulator for plotting current; it has no bearing on performance whatsoever.  The circuit is only single-quadrant.

Comment: Very good explanation. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir